# ¿Cómo hago para que se envié el formulario solo?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Tengo un código en PHP que lo que hace es que yo le paso por url mediante ?pass=1234 , esta es la contraseña, lo que me gustaría es que se enviara el formulario automáticamente sin tener que pulsar el botón del Submit el código es el siguiente

```php
function my_password_form() {
global $post;
    global $wp;
    $results;
    $url = home_url(add_query_arg(array($_GET), $wp->request));
    $components = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($components['query'], $results);
    $password = $results['pass'];
    

$label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
$o = '<form class="protected-post-form" action="' . get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-login.php?action=postpass" method="post">' . '<a href="/home/">' . __( "" ) .'</a>' . '<div style="display:none"> <label for="' .  $label . '">' . __( "Password:" )  . ' </label><input id="' . $label . '" autocomplete="off" maxlength="20" name="post_password" size="20" type="hidden" value="'.$password .'"/></div><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="'.esc_attr__( '¿ESTAS PREPARADO?') . '">  </form>';
return $o;
}
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'my_password_form' );
```

Con este código modifico una funcion the_password_form a la mía

Answer (score 1):

Podrias poner esto en el functions de tu tema.

```
function send_protected_post_form_auto(){
    if ( isset( $_GET['pass'] ) ) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery( 'form.protected-post-form' ).submit();
            });
        </script>
    <?php }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'send_protected_post_form_auto', 99 );
```

Esto ejecutará un script que enviará el formulario usando `.submit()` siempre y cuando existe la variable ?pass= en la url, asegurate de tener jQuery encolado entre tus scripts, lo más probable es que ya lo tengas pero no esta de mas revisar.

Ojo, que esto es asumiendo que el formulario ya está listo para enviarse.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias !!  , y de que manera podría integrar las dos funciones ? es decir la que me acabas de decir y la que yo ya tenía  y donde pongo el .submit. Gracias de antemano. Un saludo